# Which sound server in eOS Hera

Tags: release-hera, audio

I'd lile to know how eOS manages audio devices, does it uses ALSA, PulseAudio or what?

I am having problems with an USB mic but the `Setting > Audio` doesn't say much. Since in the past I devastated the system trying to fix audio probles, before doing anything I'd like to know

- can I install some PulseAudio utility to see if I can fix the problem? Any experience about that?
- what are the main config files about audio in eOS, where they are located?

Comment: I am having trouble with the USB microphone portion of a USB webcam. The video works, but the audio does not. I just hear clicks. I have tried the elementary OS Hera audio settings, and pulse audio volume control. Nothing fixes the audio.